ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : RoleAttribute string parameter DI problem
I am getting an error while building the project in the classes I created for role controls:

Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterFactory Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IOrderedFilter Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute'.)
System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterFactory Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute'.

This is my code:
public sealed class RoleAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _role;

    public RoleAttribute(string role = "")
    {
        _role = role;
    }

    //private readonly IUserRoleRepository _userRoleRepository;
    //public RoleAttribute(string role, IUserRoleRepository userRoleRepository)
    //{
    //    _role = role;
    //    _userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
    //}

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var userIdClaim = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (userIdClaim == null)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        //var userHasRole =
        //    _userRoleRepository
        //    .Where(p => p.UserId == userIdClaim.Value)
        //    .Include(p => p.Role)
        //    .Any(p => p.Role.Name == _role);

        //if (!userHasRole)
        //{
        //    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        //    return;
        //}
    }
}

public sealed class RoleFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RoleFilterAttribute(string role) : base(typeof(RoleAttribute))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { role };
    }
}
using Bogus;
using DefaultCorsPolicyNugetPackage;
using HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Application;
using HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Domain.Entities;
using HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure;
using HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Context;
using HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.WebAPI.Middlewares;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Formatting.Compact;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDefaultCors();

builder.Services.AddApplication(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<ExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(setup =>
{
    var jwtSecuritySheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Name = "JWT Authentication",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        Description = "Put **_ONLY_** yourt JWT Bearer token on textbox below!",

        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
        }
    };

    setup.AddSecurityDefinition(jwtSecuritySheme.Reference.Id, jwtSecuritySheme);

    setup.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    { jwtSecuritySheme, Array.Empty<string>() }
                });
});

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "Logs/log-.json", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
//
builder.Host.UseSerilog();

var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapGet("seed-data/products", async (ApplicationDbContext context) =>
    {
        var productFaker = new Faker<Urun>()
            .RuleFor(p => p.KdvOrani, 20)
            .RuleFor(p => p.ResimUrl, f => f.Image.PicsumUrl())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Aciklama, f => f.Commerce.ProductDescription())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Kodu, f => f.Commerce.Ean13())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Id, f => Guid.NewGuid())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Adi, f => f.Commerce.ProductName())
            .RuleFor(p => p.SatisFiyati, f => Convert.ToDecimal(f.Commerce.Price()));
        //
        var products = productFaker.Generate(10000);
        //
        context.AddRange(products);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.NoContent();

    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.UseExceptionHandler();

app.MapControllers();
ExtensionsMiddleware.CreateRoles(app);
ExtensionsMiddleware.CreateFirstUser(app);

app.Run();

 public static class DependencyInjection
 {
     public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         //Test Smtp
         services.AddFluentEmail("info@hixo.com").AddSmtpSender("localhost", 2525);
         //
         //Canlı
         var smtpSettings = configuration.GetSection("SmtpSettings").Get<SmtpSettings>();

         //services
         //    .AddFluentEmail(smtpSettings?.Username)
         //    .AddRazorRenderer()
         //    .AddSmtpSender(new SmtpClient(smtpSettings?.Host)
         //    {
         //        Port = smtpSettings!.Port,
         //        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpSettings.Username, smtpSettings.Password),
         //        EnableSsl = true
         //    });

         services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly);

         services.AddMediatR(conf =>
         {
             conf.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(
                 typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly, 
                 typeof(AppUser).Assembly);
             conf.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
         });

         services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly);

         services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(AuthorizationBehavior<,>));

         return services;
     }
 }

   public static class DependencyInjection
   {
       public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           {
               options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer"));
           });

           services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork>(srv => srv.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>());

           services
               .AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(cfr =>
               {
                   cfr.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
                   cfr.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                   cfr.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                   cfr.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                   cfr.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                   cfr.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                   cfr.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                   cfr.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                   cfr.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
               })
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

           services.Configure<JwtOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Jwt"));
           services.ConfigureOptions<JwtTokenOptionsSetup>();

           services.AddAuthentication()
               .AddJwtBearer();
           services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

           services.Scan(action =>
           {
               action
               .FromAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
               .AddClasses(publicOnly: false)
               .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip)
               .AsMatchingInterface()
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .WithScopedLifetime();
           });

           return services;
       }
   }

Stack trace:
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)  
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)  
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()  
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\murat\OneDrive\Belgeler\Visual Studio 2022\Projeler\HIXO.Tulpar.B2B\HIXO.Tulpar.B2B\HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.WebAPI\Program.cs:line 64  

(Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IOrderedFilter Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute'.

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'HIXO.Tulpar.B2B.Infrastructure.Authorization.RoleFilterAttribute'.

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)  
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---


Hi @Murat Kaya, could you pls share your Program.cs and how do you use the custom attribute?

Hi @Rena I added program.cs codes to the topic

Can you turn your question into an MRE? That means: reduce the amount of code to the minimal amount required to demonstrate the issue. Currently, you posted 234 lines of code. This makes it very time consuming for anyone who wishes to help you. Make it more compelling for others to help you.

Hi @Steven, you may need to read the program.cs codes to understand the problem.

Hi, you still miss out on how you are applying the RoleFilterAttribute in the controller/action? Can you share it? Thanks.
